# Directory created on external sd card is seen as binary when mounted via MTP

Tags: android, android-external-storage, mtp

My app is recording a video which is stored in '/Movies' in a subdir that I create like `/Movies/myapp`. When browsing from the device with OI filemanager everything looks fine - I can go into my dir and list the videos.  When I mount the device to my pc (Ubuntu 16.04) and go to `/Movies` my dir is shown as binary file (so I cannot go in). I am using `mkdirs()` to create the dir, no special symbols used in the name.

How can I create the subdir in order to be seen as dir when mounted?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that if the subdir name starts with capital letter like `/Movies/Myapp` everything works fine as expected.

If you have the same problem just make your subdir's name start with capital letter. Don't forget to delete manually the previously created subdir.

Comment: Very strange story indeed.